# Why is the logging module accessed without an instance?

Tags: python

I'm learning about logging in Python, but I don't understand why logging can be initialized like so:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
```

Doesn't it need something like:

```
l_instance = logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
```

Similar to how CSV does it:

```
c_instance = csv.reader()
```

Comment: ["Loggers have the following attributes and methods. Note that Loggers are never instantiated directly, but always through the module-level function `logging.getLogger(name)`"](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html)

Comment: Also, read the [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0282/) for the rationale. Tl;dr version: convenience.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at the source code to answear this question. What it does is imply adding handlers to root:

```
_acquireLock()
try:
    if len(root.handlers) == 0:
        filename = kwargs.get("filename")
        if filename:
            mode = kwargs.get("filemode", 'a')
            hdlr = FileHandler(filename, mode)
        else:
            stream = kwargs.get("stream")
            hdlr = StreamHandler(stream)
        fs = kwargs.get("format", BASIC_FORMAT)
        dfs = kwargs.get("datefmt", None)
        fmt = Formatter(fs, dfs)
        hdlr.setFormatter(fmt)
        root.addHandler(hdlr)
        level = kwargs.get("level")
        if level is not None:
            root.setLevel(level)
finally:
    _releaseLock()
```

So one reason is that the method returns `None` :D

Now, look that if you call `getLogger` method:

```
if name:
    return Logger.manager.getLogger(name)
else:
    return root
```

You cann see that it returns this created root. Same thing applies to other methods as `debug`:

```
def debug(msg, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Log a message with severity 'DEBUG' on the root logger.
    """
    if len(root.handlers) == 0:
        basicConfig()
    root.debug(msg, *args, **kwargs)
```

See? it operates on `root`. Pyton is open-source, you can make use of it ;)